# Alarm + Notification: nothing happens

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I am trying to implement an alarm that would display a notification everyday at the same hour of the day.

Here is the function I'm calling in my activity:

```
private void restartNotify() {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Intent for our BroadcastReceiver 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    // PendingIntent for AlarmManager
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );

    // In case we have already set up AlarmManager, we cancel.
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);



    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, pendingIntent);           
}
```

And here is my broadcast receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon_notif, context.getString(R.string.NotificationLaunchMssg), System.currentTimeMillis());

    // This is intent we want to launch when user clicks on the notification.
    Intent intentTL = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, context.getString(R.string.NotificationTitle), context.getString(R.string.NotificationBody),               
    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentTL, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

    nm.notify(1, notification);

    //Here we set next notification, in day interval
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, pendingIntent); 
}
}
```

As you can see in this code I am using a test value (+10000 milliseconds) because I am simply trying to trigger the alarm 10 seconds after my app has started. But it doesn't work, nothing is displayed.
I don't know if the alarm has a problem, or the notification, nothing is happening.

Do you have any idea why?

Thanks for your help

EDIT: after adding some test code in AlarmReceiver method, it turns out this code is never run. So I probably don't call it properly, what is wrong?

Comment: You are setting the alarm at 12:00, not 10 seconds after your app started. Try adding some logging information to see if the broadcast is received or not.

Comment: you are right I let dirty code in my question, I have edited now with System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: That way you ask for an alarm exactly at this time of the day. By the time it's registered that time will already be in the past.

Comment: Ok, what I don't understand is where I should set the trigger time in the future : in my function restartNotify from my activity? Or in my class AlarmReceiver ? right now I set current time in my activity, and current time + 10 sec in my class AlarmReceiver

Comment: In the activity you set when the first alarm will be triggered (you need the +10 seconds here). In the receiver you set when the next one is triggered, again you need the +10 seconds.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It still doesn not work. I am not so sure the problem is about date and time, I suspect rather a problem of passing intents or something about linking the notification with the alarm ? I haven't managed to display a single notification in the last hours !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use this approach try setInexactRepeating(...) or setRepeating(...) instead. Why are u giving extra work to the BroadcastReceiver for setting alarm every time it receives the intent.

here is a little code:

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            0, 10000, pendingIntent);
// The pending intent will the same as yours. 10000 is the 
// interval for between consecutive alarms
```

as azertiti mentioned in comments " By the time it's registered that time will already be in the past." so use 0 or System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried it and it doesnt work. I am sure your code would work, but I think my problem is not related to the date itself, maybe something with the notification, or passing intents? I can't manage to get any notification triggered

Comment: try to log some information in AlarmReceiver's onReceive method... see if it getting called

Comment: Ok I have added code to log information inside my AlarmReceiver and it is not run. What I am doing wrong in my function restartNotify so that AlarmReceiver is not properly called?

Comment: As mentioned do not use "System.currentTimeMillis()+10000".. And did you register your AlarmReceiver in manifest or programatically ? how di you register?

Comment: good idead to look into the manifest... I had
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
now it's working with
<receiver android:name="<my actual packagename fully written>.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
Thanks KKD